# Object_version_number in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle

Is object_version_number mandatory in Oracle database tables?

Even if the table description does not contain object_version_number, will the table have that column implicitly? 
If yes, Can we query the object_version_number value?

Comment: A quick Google suggests that OBJECT_VERSION_NUMBER is a column used by Oracle Applications. It's not an implicit column that the Oracle database provides on all tables, so if that column isn't present on a table, you can't use it in a query on that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not mandatory:

```
 CREATE TABLE t (n NUMBER);
 INSERT INTO t VALUES (1);

 SELECT object_version_number FROM t;
 ORA-00904: "OBJECT_VERSION_NUMBER": invalid identifier
```